# How to define a measure on a $L^2$ space?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

The intuitive motivation for this question is to consider the "probability" of a given vibration mode to be contained in a "random" perturbation. My questions is that, given an $L^2$ space, is it possible to define a measure on it in order to make sense of some "probability"?

Comment: Wiener measure?